# create ast tree of php with c++ in windows

Tags: php, c++, abstract-syntax-tree

do somebody know how i can get a AST Tree from PHP Code with C++ in Windows?

i found this in php:

https://github.com/nikic/php-ast and for example this:

https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser

in php there is a very easy way to do it - but what is with c/c++?

i tried it with astkit and some others like hhvm - but dont get a solution because the most is depending on php.

EDIT: i want to make ast of php code with c++

Comment: what are you trying to do? Parse PHP code using C++? Parse C++ code using PHP?

Comment: Have you studied http://www.phpinternalsbook.com already?